# How to extend a class with a private constructor?

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I have a class from a library with a single private constructor I need to extend (to use in unit tests). If I try to extend the class, TypeScript complains, "Cannot extend a class 'GuildMember'. Class constructor is marked as private." How would I extend this class or make the constructor not private?

```
// The parent class
export class GuildMember extends PartialTextBasedChannel(Base) {
    private constructor()
}

// The test class
class MockGuildMember extends GuildMember {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}
```

My goal is to achieve this purely in TypeScript, retaining as much of the type-checking as possible. I know this is possible in JavaScript already.

Answer (score 0):

Gross, but it worked (and I can't find any other way).

```
// @ts-expect-error Extending private class for mocking
export default class MockGuildMember extends GuildMember {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}
```